# Python custom Exception class throws TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, exception, aws-lambda

I have an Exception class written in Python for handling my custom AWS Lambda exceptions as below:

```
class HTTPException(Exception):
def __new__(cls, error_code, error_message):
    return {
        "statusCode": error_code,
        "body": error_message,
        "headers": {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    }

@classmethod
def magic_func(cls, err):
    return cls(
        error_code=err.Code,
        error_message=err.Message,
    )
```

When I try to invoke this through AWS lambda it throws: TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class HTTPException(Exception):
    def __new__(cls, error_code, error_message):
        return {
            "statusCode": error_code,
            "body": error_message,
            "headers": {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        }
```

is violating the contract for `__new__`, failing to return a new instance of `HTTPException`, and instead returning a random `dict` object. If you intended to wrap said `dict` in the exception, the sane way to do it would be to use `__init__` (because you don't want to return something that *isn't* and `HTTPException`, nor use singletons or caches or immutable objects, which are the reasons to use `__new__` instead), and delegate the `dict` up to the superclass initializer:

```
class HTTPException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_code, error_message):  # __init__ taking self
        # Pass dict up to superclass initializer
        super().__init__({
            "statusCode": error_code,
            "body": error_message,
            "headers": {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        })

    @classmethod
    def magic_func(cls, err):
        return cls(
            error_code=err.Code,
            error_message=err.Message,
        )
```

Hopefully, whatever catches your exception knows to *look* for that attached `dict`, because if not, you're going to need to find where that's happening and return the `dict` the expected way.

Comment: But I read somewhere that it isn't a good thing to return from __init__. Excuse my naiveness.

Comment: @BrattyNeal: You *don't* return from `__init__`. Look at the modified code. `__init__` *initializes* an existing object provided to it (`self`), you don't need to return a thing. `__new__` needs to return, but it should still be an instance of the `cls` passed to it, which your original code was ignoring, returning a `dict` instead.

Comment: When I try to return an Exception using your above solution, I get "Unable to marshal response: Object of type HTTPException is not JSON serializable", "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError" in my AWS API gateway for my lambda. Looks like it returns an object(class object) instead of my dict structure.

Comment: @BrattyNeal: Yes... You can't raise a `dict` as an exception. You can *extract* the `dict` from the exception wherever you catch it, should you need to return it (the `.args` attribute of the exception is a `tuple` containing the arguments, so `exceptionobject.args[0]` will be your `dict`). I have a feeling you've got [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here, or a fundamental misunderstanding of how exceptions work. You can *only* raise instances of `BaseException` or its subclasses. AWS wants you to return a `dict`. Trying to mix the two too closely will fail.

Comment: Are you stating that maintaining a custom Exception class was a bad idea ?

Comment: @BrattyNeal: No, nothing wrong with that, but you can't just make it act like returning a `dict` on its own. Go ahead, wrap your whole function in `try:`/`except HTTPException as e: return e.args[0]`. Maybe it'll work? I don't know AWS's system. The important part is the understand what you're doing, and I'm not sure you do. Exceptions are great when you need exceptions. But you can't make them be anything other than exceptions without extra work.

Comment: Thanks for this statement. Maybe next time you can be less rude and more informative :)